Is the $2p$ RPD defined along the z-axis?
In MIT $5.111$ class (lecture $6$), we are to compare the most probable radius of a $2s$ orbital and a $2p$ orbital. The graph used by the professor represents the RPD versus $r$:

My question is: in the second figure, are we talking about the RPD along the z-axis (i.e. across a $2p_z$ orbital) or are we talking about the RPD across all the space ?
My guess is that the latter is true.
My guess is based on the fact that the RPD is always the derivative relative to $r$ of $\int \int \int | \psi|^2 dV $, hence no specific axis is used to get the RPD.
Can anyone confirm if my reasoning is right ?

Your reasoning is right. The meaning of RPD is the same as always. There is nothing left to guess.
